# Rails - Link_to_remote a big name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hyperlink

I need to use link_to_remote, but instead of using something like link_to_remote "a small name" I need to set a partial as a name. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply set the rendering of your partial as the 'name' for the `link_to_remote`:

```
link_to_remote(render(:partial => 'my_partial'), 
               :url => some_url, 
               :update => 'some_id')
```